# android broadcast receiver must be registered when the broadcast is sent?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Is it correct, that, if the broadcast is sent while there is no registered broadcast receiver, the broadcast is lost?

For some reason i thought, that if the broadcast was sent while there was no active receiver, the broadcast would "circle around" the app (I am using `LocalBroadcastManager`) and would be delivered to a receiver, if such receiver was registered later.

P.s. I've seen in many examples, where the receiver is released when the activity goes in background. I guess that is for improving resource management. So my other question is, if i wanted my activity to receive broadcasts while being in background, would it be a major resource waste if i kept the receiver active during all of the activity life duration?

Comment: "if the broadcast is sent while there is no registered broadcast receiver, the broadcast is lost?" -- correct, except for sticky broadcasts. "if the broadcast was sent while there was no active receiver, the broadcast would "circle around" the app (I am using LocalBroadcastManager) and would be delivered to a receiver, if such receiver was registered later." -- there is no sticky broadcast option for `LocalBroadcastManager`.

Comment: to CommonsWare: thank you for answering. I have a following question: is there any difference regarding resource management, how i implement the broadcast receiver? (related to the P.s. part of my question)